# the (2,2,1) boundedness of a "product" operator

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

This question is from MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191551/the-2-2-1-boundedness-of-a-product-operator
It seems easy but turns out very difficult.

Let $\{E_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\{F_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be two collections of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $C(j,k)$ be a bounded function (e.g. $|C(j,k)|<1$) defined on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. For Schwartz functions $f$ and $g$, consider the operator
$$ T(f,g)=\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}C(j,k)f_j g_k $$
where $f_j$ and $g_k$ are defined by $\hat{f_j}=\hat{f}1_{E_j}$ and $\hat{g_k}=\hat{g}1_{F_k}$.

It seems that $T$ is similar to the product operator $fg$ or a paraproduct. So we may have $\|T(f,g)\|_1\le C\|f\|_2\|g\|_2$ for some absolute constant $C$ and I'm trying to prove it. If the function $C(j,k)$ is independent of one of $j$ and $k$, then I can write the double sum as a product of two single sums and proceed with Cauchy-Schwarz and Plancherel. The real difficulty is that $C(j,k)$ depends on both $j$ and $k$. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it essential that $T$ be strong ((2,2),1) bounded?

Comment: I want to show that $T$ is strong (2,2,1) bounded. The coefficients $C(j,k)$ make the problem hard.

Comment: Sorry, I mean do you know that $T$ is strong (2,2,1) bounded (i.e. this question is motivated by a homework problem) or do you suspect that it is and are trying to prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure about the boundedness. I suspect it is true and I'm trying to prove it. You may also try to disprove it.

Comment: Were you ever able to prove the desired boundedness?

Comment: @MattRosenzweig No. The coefficients are too general (even they are bounded) to get any good results.